# Not showing products which not enough credit for

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a vending machine and I don't want to show products which there isn't enough credit for right now. I have come up with:

```
credit = 0 
prices = [30,80,65,90,100]
if credit == products:
     print(products)
```

However this doesn't seem to be working is there anything else I can use?

Comment: `for credit == products` I have no idea what you think that's going to do. Please take some time to read [help] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a dictionary for your products/prices. This way they can be associated to each other.

```
credit = 0
prices = {"product1": 30, "product2": 80, "product3": 65, "product4": 90,
          "product5": 100}
for product in prices:
     if credit >= prices[product]:
         print(product " - " + prices[product])
```

if credit is 70 output will be:

product1 - 30

product3 - 65

Comment: thank you for your code is there anyway I can do it without using a dictionary ?

Comment: You could try looping through two arrays simultaneously, and probably a dozen other ways, but a dictionary is likely the easiest way.

Comment: You should read through some documentation on loops. Check out "for" loops and "while" loops.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the prices of products the consumer can purchase:

```
for product in prices:
    if product <= credits:
        print product
```

Since you didn't specify what `products` is, I can't really help much further.